# How to get all the means in a wikipedia disambiguation page?

Tags: wikipedia

I try to use JWPL API in my project. I need to get all the means in a certain disambiguation page. For example  a disambiguation page about [Apple](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_tree_%28disambiguation%29).

I will be grateful if you can tell me something about that!

Comment: I don't know JWPL, but it should be enough to get all the links to articles in that page.

Comment: Given a term, can you get the disambiguation page of that? If you can, could you tell me how ?

Comment: You could try `Term` and then `Term (disambiguation)`. You know for sure that page is a disambiguation page when it's in the category [All disambiguation pages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:All_disambiguation_pages).

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if you still need and answer but in short, if you want to collect all possible meanings for a given word don't use the disambiguation pages.
Why? Because they are not well formatted and often contain a lot of links that do not correspond to a certain meaning of a word. Even if you only parse the first lines starting with * and collect the first link in that line you still would get wrong results.
Instead you should collect all the links in wikipedia and store their anchor text as keyword and the target article as possible meaning for that keyword. As a side effect you get nice statistics about how often a word corresponds to a certain meaning. Another resource for possible meanings are the redirect pages and Article titles. For example: You can collect all articles with the same entity but different disambiguation part and use them as possible meanings for that entity.

If you want a more detail explanation just answer in the comments, i can also supply some code on how to collect and Index containing possible meanings for all redirects, entities and link-texts contained in Wikipedia with jwpl.

Comment: Do you get all the links from a Wikipedia dump? It seems unfortunate that the pagelinks.sql dump doesn't include the anchor text...

Comment: I use the jwpl api, it needs the pages-articles.xml, pagelinks.sql and categorylinks.sql and loads them into your database you can then access them with the api.  http://code.google.com/p/jwpl/wiki/DataMachine